# Map an abstract collection with generics in JPA

Tags: java, generics, jpa, collections, abstract

I have an abstract and generic class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Field<T> {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "field_id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "FIELD_SECTION")
    private List<Section> sections;
}
```

with a couple of classes extending it, such as:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
public class StringField extends Field<String> {
}
```

or

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
public class DateField extends Field<Date> {
}
```

I also have a Section class, which contains an abstract collection of Field

```
@Entity
public class Section {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "section_id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "sections")
    private List<Field<?>> fields;
}
```

However, the JPA cannot properly map the `List<Field<?>> fields` collection which results in the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.model.Section.fields[com.model.field.Field]
```

Basicly, it should be doable, since the `FIELD_SECTION` table would hold a pair of `(section_id, field_id)`. Each type of field would have a separate table, but all of the `field_id`'s would be unique in all of the field tables, allowing the JPA to determine the type of each field.

Is there a way to achieve the above?

Comment: The primary problem you have (created) is that you have a Field but the "id" is not unique across all Field objects ... because StringField will have its own unique id, and DateField will have its own unique field ... but objects of those types are still Field objects. If the Field had a table then fine.